# Weka LibSVM one class classifier always predicts one class

Tags: classification, weka, libsvm, arff

I'm trying to use LibSVM classifier in Weka to build a one class SVM classifier.

My training file has list of **noun words**. 
My test file has many words. My aim is to use the classifier to predict the words which are nouns in test file.

My input arff file (*ip.arff*)(training file) looks like this:

```
@relation test1

@attribute name string
@attribute class {yes}

@data
'building',yes
'car',yes
..... and so on
```

My test file(*test.arff*) (test file) looks like this:

```
@relation test2

@attribute name string
@attribute class {yes}

@data
'car',?
'window',?
'running',?
..... and so on
```

Here's what I've done:

1. Since the datatype is string, I used *batch Filtering* on both input files to generate
   *ipstd.arff* and *teststd.arff* as mentioned in
   http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering
2. Next i load and run the classifier with *ipstd.arff*. (Note: All the words are classified as yes)
3. Next I load the test set *teststd.arff* and re-evaluate the model.
4. But all the words are classified as nouns('yes')

   `=== Predictions on user test set ===`

   `inst#     actual  predicted error prediction`

   ```
     1        1:?      1:yes       1 
     2        1:?      1:yes       1
     3        1:?      1:yes       1
   ```

   `and so on`

**My problem is that all words in test file(*teststd.arff*) are classified as nouns**

Can someone tell where I'm going wrong..
What should I do classify noun words in test set with 'yes' and others as outliers.
Thanks...

Comment: Providing negative examples would be a good start. You cannot get "no" if you don't train for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have a doubt. My libSVM is one class SVM. So i don't get the point of giving negative examples.

Comment: My problem is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394615/unary-class-text-classification-in-weka). ie the comments in accepted answer

Comment: Did you find the solution to your issue? Your linked post didnt help me