# One class SVM to detect outliers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, libsvm, arff

My problem is

> I want to build a **one class SVM classifier** to identify the nouns/aspects from test file.
>   The training file has list of nouns. The test has list of words.

This is what I've done:

I'm using Weka GUI and I've trained a one class SVM(libSVM) to get a model.

> Now the model classifies those words in test file that the classifier identified as nouns in the generated model. Others are classified as outliers. ( So it is just working like a look up. If it is identified as noun in trained model, then 'yes' else 'no')

So how to build a proper classifier?. ( I meant the format of input and what it information it should contain?)

Note:

- I don't give negative examples in training file since it is one class.
- My input format is *arff*
- Format of training file is a set of **word,yes**
- Format of test file is a set of **word,?**

**EDIT**
My test file will have **noun phrases**. So my classifier's job is to get the nouns words from candidates in test file.

Comment: I am not sure it makes sense to talk about a "one-class" classifier. I would frame yours as a two-class problem ("noun" and "non-noun"). Generally, you'd need examples from both classes in order to train a classifier.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But one clas classification is spoken here.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394615/unary-class-text-classification-in-weka)

Comment: Oh, you mean outlier detection.

Comment: Yes.. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: Recommendation: update the title of your post to reflect outlier detection vs one-class : it becomes more clear.

Comment: Do you use unigrams, bigrams or?

Comment: @badc0re I'm using unigrams.

Comment: For unigrams you don't even need a classier.

Answer (score 5):

Your data is not formatted appropriately for this problem.

If you put

```
word,class
```

pairs into a SVM, what you are *really* putting into the SVM are *sparse vectors* that consist of a single one, corresponding to your word, i.e.

```
0,0,0,0,0,...,0,0,1,0,0,0,...,0,0,0,0,yes
```

**Anything a classifier can do on such data is overfit and memorize. On unknown new words, the result will be useless.**

---

If you want your classifier to be able to *abstract* and *generalize*, then **you need to carefully extract features from your words**.

Possible features would be n-grams. So the word "example" could be represented as

```
exa:1, xam:1, amp:1, mpl:1, ple:1
```

Now your classifier/SVM could learn that having the n-gram "ple" is typical for nouns.
Results will likely be better if you add "beginning-of-word" and "end-of-word" symbol,

```
^ex:1, exa:1, xam:1, amp:1, mpl:1, ple:1, le$:1
```

and maybe also use more than one n-gram length, e.g.

```
^ex:1, ^exa:1, exa:1, exam: 1, xam:1, xamp:1, amp:1, ampl:1, mpl:1, mple1:1, ple:1, ple$.1, le$:1
```

but of course, the more you add the larger your data set and search space grows, which again may lead to overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. And my test file actually will not have arbitrary words.It will have noun phrases from which I want to get nouns. That is my classifier's job.